# Can you breakpoint into Dalvik to debug an Android Application?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator

I have a performance issue with an AppWidget.  If I make a change and wait for 45 seconds before exiting the application, the widget receives the Intent and I see the screen change.  If I exit out more quickly, I see the code being executed according to the Log.d(...) calls but the GUI is not updated.

This leads me to want to get the android source code, hook it up to eclipse.  Compile the source.  Make a virtual device. Run eclipse and break point into the dalvik layer.

Can I do this? Does it makes sense?  I've pulled down the android source.  I've done the lunch-eng and make -j thing.  But I'm confused about what step comes next.

Comment: can I use the emulator or do I have use a physical device for debugging?

Comment: This apparently is not for the faint of heart ... https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-porting/GKGVEz126PE